# How to pass values from one page to another in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have two pages of jQuery, Page1 and Page2, and I'm able to get input in Page1.

The `somval=1000$`.

The page 1 user enters the somevalue. I have stored the value:

```
var val = somval;
```

Now in the second page, I need to get the result of somvalue in page 1. Of course two pages using My1.js My2.js respectively.

How do I share the values from one jQuery file to other JavaScript or how do I get the value from page1 value, to page2?

How do I tackle this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can redirect the user to the next page with the data in a query string, then in the second page you can parse the URL.

To redirect the user you can do this:

```
window.location = 'page2.html?somval=' + somval;
```

Then in the second page you can use a function to parse the URL query string:

```
var qsParm = new Array();
function qs() {
    var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var parms = query.split('&');
    for (var i=0; i < parms.length; i++) {
        var pos = parms[i].indexOf('=');
        if (pos > 0) {
            var key = parms[i].substring(0, pos);
            var val = parms[i].substring(pos + 1);
            qsParm[key] = val;
        }
    }
}
```

This code was borrowed from [here](http://javascript.about.com/library/blqs.htm), although there are [many ways to do it](http://www.google.com.au/search?q=parse+query+strings+javascript).

You mentioned jQuery, but correct me if I'm wrong, I don't think it can do this.

Answer (score 1):

You could set the data in a cookie, http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html has functions for reading and writing cookies.

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't specific to jQuery (ie. it probably haven't a specific solution, unless I am mistaken), but to any Web page.
Gerald gave the URL query string solution, the other classical solution, if you want to be independent of a server, is to use cookies, they are made for that!
Using a server, you have session data, hidden fields, Ajax save and restore, etc.