# pass value displayed in a div to another page in php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I just wanted to if there is a way to pass value that has been displayed in `DIV id` to another page
My data is called form another page and displayed here in the given code

```
<div id="res" style="float: left; Padding-left: 3px; padding-right:13px;line-height: 15px;">
      ......
</div>
```

and i want to pass the value being displayed here to another page this is a php page.
Thanks...

Comment: You can use a cookie to store that value and access in another page.

Comment: thank man helped a lot easy eating pie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure you can.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var resval = $('#res').text();  
});
```

Then, redirect the user to the next page with the data in a query string:

```
window.location = 'page2.html?resval=' + resval;
```

then in the second page you can parse the URL (in JQuery):

```
var qsParm = new Array();
function qs() {
    var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var parms = query.split('&');
    for (var i=0; i < parms.length; i++) {
        var pos = parms[i].indexOf('=');
        if (pos > 0) {
            var key = parms[i].substring(0, pos);
            var val = parms[i].substring(pos + 1);
            qsParm[key] = val;
        }
    }
}
```

Or, you can get the parameter by using `$_GET['resval']` in PHP.

Referenced: [How to pass values from one page to another in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/404891/how-to-pass-values-from-one-page-to-another-in-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

on another page put hidden field and store your value after in div tag get value using echo  $_request. now it will be display in div tag

Answer (score 0):

You tagged jquery and ajax so here is a jquery and ajax solution to pass the content of the div, to another page. In this example I use `.text()` but if you want to grab the raw HTML then use `.html()` instead.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var content = $('#res').text();

    $.ajax({
       url: 'test.php',
       type: 'POST',
       data: { mytext : content },
       success: function(data) {

        // success - do something

      }
    });

});
```

Edit: for clarification this is Javascript/jQuery code. It goes on the page with the div. I have added a `$(document).ready` wrapper, so that it is called when the page loads, but you can put this code in any event, for example a button click.

Also, because this is an ajax call, the user will not see anything happen when the call is made. The user will not be redirected to the second page.

On the PHP page that receives the content, you can access it with `$_POST['mytext']`.

Comment: where am i suppose to use this code in the test.php page or in my div page ?

Comment: @AyushMalakar I have added an edit to clarify - this code goes on the page with the div.