# auto click button after another button was clicked on other page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I got 2 pages: index.html and contact.html and each of them have a button (a tag for index page). When I click a button on the contact page, it should redirect to the index page and auto click  on the index page. Is this possible?

Here my index page:

```
<div id = "wrapper"> 

  <a id="btn-show-content" href="#"></a>

</div>
```

Here's my contact page:

```
<div id = "contact-wrapper">
    <button id="btn-back"></button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add query to button in contact page

```
<div id = "contact-wrapper">
  <a href="index.html#triggerbtn"></a>
</div>
```

Then, when the index page loads, it triggers triggerMe() function in the index page, you do the check of url hash

```
 <body onload="triggerMe()"></body>
 <script>
    function triggerMe() {
       var check = location.hash;
       if (check == "triggerbtn") {
           //button trigger even though you do not click on it
           $('#btn-show-content').trigger('click');    
       }
    }
 </script>
```

I assume that you only need to trigger the function when click button in contact page. If you need the action happen all time you go to index page, you can use

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#btn-show-content').trigger('click');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the JQuery `.trigger()` function. For your problem you wish to click a button on the contact page and it'll redirect you to the index page. When you go onto the index page and the document loads, this function will be performed.

Documentation [here](https://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

```
(document).ready(function(){
  $('#id').trigger('click');
});
```

In order to take away the issue of not being able to use Index.html everytime without it autoclicking. You can pass over a value to trigger the function on contact.html and then parse it in index.html, check out the solution to this question for that:

[How to pass values from one page to another in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/404891/how-to-pass-values-from-one-page-to-another-in-jquery)

Comment: Can you be more specific?