# Active border (.showBorder) centered under text as it moves

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, user-interface, jquery-ui

```js
// Get references to the two sets of boxes
var numbers = document.querySelectorAll(".clicked");
var letters = document.querySelectorAll(".border");

// Turn each node list into proper arrays:
numbers = Array.prototype.slice.call(numbers);
letters = Array.prototype.slice.call(letters);

// Loop through all the number boxes
numbers.forEach(function(box, index) {

  // Set up the click event handlers for all the number boxes
  box.addEventListener("click", function() {

    // Remove borders from each of the letter boxes
    letters.forEach(function(box) {
      box.classList.remove("showBorder");
    });

    // Apply the border to only the one clicked element
    var info = document.getElementsByClassName('box-tip')[0];
    info.style.left = 10 + (index * 45) + 'px';
    info.style.visibility = 'visible';
    letters[index].classList.add("showBorder");
  });

});

$(document).on("click", '.clicked', function(){
    $('.clicked').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

```css
.list-box li {display: inline-block;list-style-type: none;padding: 1em;background:red;}
.list-box {margin:15px auto;padding:0;}
.box-sleeve li {display: inline-block;list-style-type: none;padding: 1em;background:red;}
.box-sleeve {margin:15px auto;padding:0;}
.showBorder { border: 3px dashed black; }

.box-tip {
  display:inline;
  margin: auto;
 position: relative;
 visibility: hidden; 
 }

.numberCircle {
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 12px;
  border: 5px solid #000;
  color: #fff;
  background: #000;
}

.numberCircle span {
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
}

li.selected {color:#fff;background-color:#000;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list-box">
  <li class="clicked">1</li>
  <li class="clicked">2</li>
  <li class="clicked">3</li>
  <li class="clicked">4</li>
  <li class="clicked">5</li>
  <li class="clicked">6</li>
  <li class="clicked">7</li>
  <li class="clicked">8</li>
</ul>
<div class="box-tip">
  <span class="info">Regular length for your collar size</span>
  <span class="numberCircle">?</span>
</div>
<ul class="box-sleeve">
  <li class="border">a</li>
  <li class="border">b</li>
  <li class="border">c</li>
  <li class="border">d</li>
  <li class="border">e</li>
  <li class="border">f</li>
  <li class="border">g</li>
  <li class="border">h</li>
</ul>
```

The active letter box (.showBorder) needs to be in the centre of the text 'Regular length for your collar size' as the text moves. The text start position should be left aligned as it currently is. In order to be centered with the border box it needs to only start moving when hits letter 'C'. All recommendations are welcome. Here's my code:

```js
// Get references to the two sets of boxes
var numbers = document.querySelectorAll(".click");
var letters = document.querySelectorAll(".border");

// Turn each node list into proper arrays:
numbers = Array.prototype.slice.call(numbers);
letters = Array.prototype.slice.call(letters);

// Loop through all the number boxes
numbers.forEach(function(box, index) {

  // Set up the click event handlers for all the number boxes
  box.addEventListener("click", function() {

    // Remove borders from each of the letter boxes
    letters.forEach(function(box) {
      box.classList.remove("showBorder");
    });

    // Apply the border to only the one clicked element
    var info = document.getElementsByClassName('box-tip')[0];
    info.style.left = 10 + (index * 45) + 'px';
    info.style.visibility = 'visible';
    letters[index].classList.add("showBorder");
  });

});
```

```css
.list-box li {display: inline-block;list-style-type: none;padding: 1em;background:red;}
.list-box {margin:50px auto;padding:0;}
.box-sleeve li {display: inline-block;list-style-type: none;padding: 1em;background:red;}
.box-sleeve {margin:50px auto;padding:0;}
.showBorder { border: 3px dashed black; }

.box-tip {
  display:inline;
  margin: auto;
 position: relative;
 visibility: hidden; 
 }

.numberCircle {
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 12px;
  border: 5px solid #000;
  color: #fff;
  background: #000;
}

.numberCircle span {
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list-box">
  <li class="click">1</li>
  <li class="click">2</li>
  <li class="click">3</li>
  <li class="click">4</li>
  <li class="click">5</li>
  <li class="click">6</li>
  <li class="click">7</li>
  <li class="click">8</li>
</ul>
<div class="box-tip">
  <span class="info">Regular length for your collar size</span>
  <span class="numberCircle">?</span>
</div>
<ul class="box-sleeve">
  <li class="border">a</li>
  <li class="border">b</li>
  <li class="border">c</li>
  <li class="border">d</li>
  <li class="border">e</li>
  <li class="border">f</li>
  <li class="border">g</li>
  <li class="border">h</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `info.style.left = 10 + (index * 45) + 'px';`

```
 if (index > 2) {
  info.style.left = 10 + ((index - 3) * 45) + 'px';
}
else {
info.style.left = 0 + 'px';
}
```

this is the fiddle for it: https://jsfiddle.net/flish/fm6821d5/
Updated now and works better

Comment: great answer. Only flaw is when I click back to number 1 the text doesn't go back to the starting position. any idea how that can be achieved?

Comment: True. I didn't think of that.

Comment: Ah I see. Legend!

Comment: one more thing - if the field .marimea has been preselected or remembered on a different page and the user lands on this page again with the field being selected, how can I make the border show on the relevant letter?

Comment: First .marimea was just something to get rid of the .click class. Feel free to change it back, although it is very inadvisable to name a class with an action (classes with the names click, blur, submit, keydown etc will just confuse you when there's hundreds of lines of javascript).                                For passing variables see this: https://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html   as a quick guide to cookies. In fact see this question and answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/404891/how-to-pass-values-from-one-page-to-another-in-jquery

Comment: is it possible to amend current script to if .marimea active then .showborder is active no matter whether the selection was made on current page or another page?