# Passing object array to another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i've made a button "checkout" in which when it's pressed it will gather all the data in a html table into an object array. The problem is how do i pass the ***var arrData*** data to the next page. New to jquery, thanks in advance.

```
$("#checkout").on('click',function(){

var arrData=[];
$("#table tr").each(function(){
    var currentRow=$(this);

    var col1_value=currentRow.find("td:eq(0)").text();
    var col2_value=currentRow.find("td:eq(1)").text();
    var col3_value=currentRow.find("td:eq(2)").text();
    var col4_value=currentRow.find("td:eq(3)").text();


    var obj={};
    obj.col1=col1_value;
    obj.col2=col2_value;
    obj.col3=col3_value;
    obj.col4=col4_value;


    arrData.push(obj);
});
console.log(arrData);

});
```

Comment: Not possible with jQuery, you need to pass obj as query parameter in your URL and then read/parse the url in other page

Comment: @Helpinghand can u give an example, still blurry.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/404891/how-to-pass-values-from-one-page-to-another-in-jquery

Comment: When you switch to another page all variables are refreshed. Hence passing through url is a good option. Local storage is another way as well

Comment: i understood the theory but how do i apply it as a code ,, can u make 1 good answer for beginners like me. @Helpinghand

Comment: Provided the localStorage way, check the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Not to complicate things you can use `localStorage` to locally store data in browser.
This way you can use the data whenever you want from any page in your website.

Set arrData in local storage from page 1.

```
localStorage.myArrData=JSON.stringify(arrData);
```

Get value of arrData in page 2,

```
var arrData = JSON.parse(localStorage.myArrData);
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sending this data to a backend? All that this code does is append the details to an object Array. 
Typically the data is passed to a backend system and subsequently can be retrieved from the same in any other pages.

Comment: No backend. I just want to load the same data table on page 1 to another table on page 2.

Comment: `var arrData=[];`  can be defined outside the scope of the call back function as a global variable, where your other data table will also be able to access it. In that way you would be able to access the data.

Comment: the other table is on the next page, not the same page.

Comment: Explain why this is an answer to the question.

Comment: The scope of your arrData is within a call back function which is unavailable out of its scope. So it would definitely not be available outside.  So by different page, I believe you are talking about a different HTML file where you have included the javascript method. As far as I know there is no straightforward way.  If you are looking at building a Single page application like solution, I would suggest you to look into options such as Angular/ React which have solved this problem already, rather than build everything with jquery

Comment: @ArunMadhavanGovindarajan i've fixed and declared the arrData as global but when i try to check it on the next page via console, it says "arrData is not defined"

Comment: can you confirm if the "other page" is a separate HTML? Are you just doing a redirect to a new page like an `<a href="otherpage.html">` ? If that is the case the total context of your current page is destroyed.  What I would suggest is to have a parent HTML page, and include both these HTMLs inside that as separate divs. Depending on what you want to view, you can hide and show the pages. this way, you would be able to keep the common data as part of the base HTML and it would work across.

Comment: yes it is a seperate HTML .I've created an index.php page and declared the arrData on it and included the page to both the 1st page and 2nd page. The 1st page append the data to the arrData but when i redirect to the next page. the arrData has nothing in it. @ArunMadhavanGovindarajan